# The number of partitions of $n$.......Subbarao

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

(Subbarao) The number of partitions of $n$ in which each part appears 
two, three, or five times equals the number of partitions of $n$ into parts 
congruent to $2, 3, 6, 9,$ or $10$ modulo $12$.

Someone please give a Hint(direction) to the problem....to start with .

Comment: Have you seen, for example, the proof using generating functions that the number of partitions of $n$ into odd parts and the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts are the same? The proof of this uses a similar technique.

Comment: Although this question is older, it is now a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145914/gen-func-the-number-of-partitions-of-n-where-each-part-occurs-2-3-5-times-n?rq=1), which has solutions.